# Efficiency of Malloc function in CUDA

Tags: cuda, malloc

I am trying to port some CPU codes into CUDA. My CUDA card is based on Fermi architecture, and therefore I can use the malloc() function in the device to dynamically allocate memory and don't need to change the original codes a lot. (The malloc() function is called many times in my codes.) My question is if this malloc function is efficient enough, or we should avoid to use it if possible. I don't get much speedup running my codes on CUDA, and I doubt this is caused by the use of malloc() function.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion or comment. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current device malloc implementation is very slow (there has been papers published about efficient CUDA dynamic memory allocation, but that work has not yet appeared in a release toolkit, AFAIK). The memory it allocates comes from heap, which is stored global memory, and it is also very slow. Unless you have a very compelling reason to do so, I would recommend avoiding in kernel dynamic memory allocation. It will have a negative effect on overall performance. Whether it is actually have much effect on *your code* is a completely separate question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you point me to the link of the paper?

Comment: The thesis upon which the paper was based is available [here](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/handle/2142/16137).